# Azure WebJob Loses Connection Strings

Tags: c#, azure, web-config, connection-string, app-config

I have a web job in Azure with the following code:

```
    public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("ticketprocessorqueue")] string message, TextWriter log)
    {
        foreach (var c in ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
        {
            log.WriteLine(c.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Immediately after I publish the web job and trigger it, I get the following output:

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=****;AccountKey=****

DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=****;AccountKey=****

Server=tcp:northtech.database.windows.net,1433;Database=****;User
ID=****;Password=*****;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

And that's what I would expect. However, when I trigger the same web job 30 minutes later, I get this:

```
""
```

Absolutely nothing. What's happening to my connection strings?

This is a snippet of what is in my app config (for the web job) as well as the web config (for the parent web app):

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AzureWebJobsDashboard" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=****;AccountKey=****" />
    <add name="AzureWebJobsStorage" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=****;AccountKey=****" />
    <add name="RingCloneDatabase" connectionString="Server=tcp:northtech.database.windows.net,1433;Database=****;User ID=****;Password=****;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

What's happening to my connection strings?

Comment: A couple things to try: 1) Try CloudConfigurationManager 2) Try restarting your App Service. Sorry that this doesn't really dig down to the heart of the issue but I've seen funny things happen a couple times where that was the solution. I didn't actually understand the problem itself, though.

Comment: Well, and that's the thing. If I restart the app service, it works properly again, but only for a limited time. After a period of time, the connection strings are gone again.

Comment: Okay, then there goes my theory. The scenario I've seen the weird behavior was when deploying a webjob and then changing an appsetting/connstr - they got out of sync (sometimes) until a restart. With what you're describing, it's different. Sorry I couldn't help - this does sound really strange.

Comment: Have you tried to add connection strings in the Webapp appsetting and set Webapp **Always On**?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Tom, but __Always On__ is turned on. And the settings are in the web config file for the parent web app (as well as the app config file for the web job)

Comment: On my option, add the connection string in the [Azure WebApp appsetting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure) maybe a suggestion way. You could have a try. But it still very odd that get empty string after about 30 min. You also could [scale up and scale back service plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview#scale-an-app-service-plan)  to check it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging, I found (partially) what was causing the connection strings to "disappear" in my web job. I say "partially" because I found a way to fix it, but the action I performed to "fix" it doesn't make any sense. If anyone can shed some light on it, feel free to chime in.

What it came down to was this: I recently created an additional "Deployment slot" in my azure app service. And we were using this additional deployment slot to test the app before a final deployment (a staging environment). The trouble seemed to start when I added that deployment slot. When I removed that deployment slot completely, the problem went away. So, that's it. That's all I know.

But this creates many more questions for me. And here are some thoughts and questions to consider:

1. The connection strings and app settings were exactly the same in my parent app service and my additional deployment slot.
2. On the traffic routing, I had 100% of all traffic going to my main (parent) app service, and 0% going to the staging deployment slot (we hit the staging url directly for all staging tests).
3. This seems to indicate that there was some sort of conflict in the connection strings and/or app settings between the web jobs in my parent app service and the web jobs in my deployment slot.
4. If this is the case, how does azure determine which web job "instance" to use when there is one in the parent app, and the same one in the deployment slot?
5. Even if there was a conflict between my parent app service and my deployment slot, Why would it just be blank? Wouldn't it pick up the connection string from that "instance".
6. Finally, how does azure handle web jobs that are in a deployment slot, when that same job is in the parent app? I mean, both jobs use the same queue name. Do they both get fired off when a message is added to the queue?

I can't seem to find any how deployment slots relate to web jobs. I see how to route some of your web traffic to one deployment slot or another. But nothing about the web jobs. Can anyone shed any light on this? Has anyone experienced symptoms like this before?